Loop through record type var and insert values to target table using pl/sql
I have this table TABLE_BB (firstname, lastname, id).
I also have a record type:
EMPREC is record(fname varchar,lname varchar2,idty varchar2);
type emprectype is TABLE OF EMPREC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

I need to call a procedure and loop over the record type variable value and insert into target TABLE_BB:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYPKG IS
emprec is record(fname varchar,lname varchar2,idty varchar2);
type  is table of emprectype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER; 
PROCEDURE proc_aaa (    
p_emp      IN emprectype,
x_status_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
x_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
);
END MYPKG;

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body MYPKG as
PROCEDURE proc_aaa (    
p_emp      IN emprectype,
x_status_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
x_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
) IS

BEGIN
FOR i in 1 .. p_emp.count
LOOP
insert into table_BB values (p_emp(i).fname,p_emp(i).lname,p_emp(i).idty);
END LOOP;

END proc_aaa;
    

But the compilation states that p_emp is not a cursor.
How to iterate over this variable value?

Please share a minimal reproducible case, not just snippets.

updated the code in original question

Is EMPREC defined in a package or in the schema ? Pls share complete code. That first line is not executable code

edited the above as requested

Please take some time to create that minimal reproducible example. If you expect people to help you, then make it as easy as possible to help you by providing runnable code. That code is not runnable, you have not tested it yourself before adding it to the question. Create code, test it, then update your question.

i admit my mistake koen..Sorry. i was working on project code that cant be shared. hence created dummy case here. Now i edited the code, it works fine now.

@BalaganeshMohanavel Do NOT edit the question to fix the code as that means that the question no longer makes sense as a question; instead, put the fixed code in the answer.

sure..i was looking for FORALL in. mistakenly put LOOP context. Now it works fine after remove LOOP and just use FORALL. I used  p_emp.first and  p_emp.last for index, works as expected in my OIC.

You:

Are missing the TYPE keyword in the emprec declaration;
Can use %TYPE in the declaration of the record;
Have not got an identifier for the TABLE type; and
Should use FORALL (rather than a FOR loop) - assuming that your indexes start a 1 and are contiguous; if you can have a sparse collection then you should use START and NEXT to iterate over the collection:

Like this:
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MYPKG
AS
  TYPE emprec IS RECORD(
    fname TABLE_BB.FNAME%TYPE,
    lname TABLE_BB.LNAME%TYPE,
    idty  TABLE_BB.IDTY%TYPE
  );
  TYPE emprectype IS TABLE OF emprec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  PROCEDURE proc_aaa (    
    p_emp      IN emprectype,
    x_status_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
    x_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
  );
END MYPKG;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE body MYPKG as
  PROCEDURE proc_aaa (    
    p_emp      IN emprectype,
    x_status_code   OUT VARCHAR2,
    x_error_message OUT VARCHAR2
  )
  IS
  BEGIN
    FORALL i IN 1 .. p_emp.COUNT
      insert into table_BB values (p_emp(i).fname,p_emp(i).lname,p_emp(i).idty);
  END proc_aaa;
END;
/

Then, if you have the table:
CREATE TABLE table_bb (
  fname VARCHAR2(255),
  lname VARCHAR2(255),
  idty VARCHAR2(255)
)

You can use:
DECLARE
  v_emps MYPKG.EMPRECTYPE;
  v_status VARCHAR2(4000);
  v_error  VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  v_emps(1).FNAME := 'Alice';
  v_emps(1).LNAME := 'Abbot';
  v_emps(1).IDTY  := 'AAAAA';
  v_emps(2).FNAME := 'Beryl';
  v_emps(2).LNAME := 'Baron';
  v_emps(2).IDTY  := 'BBBBB';
  mypkg.proc_aaa(v_emps, v_status, v_error);
END;
/ 

And table_bb will contain:



FNAME
LNAME
IDTY




Alice
Abbot
AAAAA


Beryl
Baron
BBBBB



fiddle
